# Issue warning for wrong size of initialiizer list of static array

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, enums, initializer

Very short: How can I enable a warning in gcc and/or VS for codes like:

```
const int array[4] = {1, 2};
```

Longer version: I have a table with constant properties. Basicly it defines how 2 "objects" interact. For that I have a table that got 3 dimensions: Environment, 1st Object, 2nd Object. There are 3 different environments (enum), and ~20 objects. So the array looks like:

```
const int property[3][20][20] = {{{...}}, {{...}}, {{...}}};
```

(In the real code 3 and 20 are the actual count constants of the enum. One could also make the int an enum but thats not the point.)
So an access of property[e][t1][t2] means: How should I handle the meeting t1->t2 in environment e? Note that this is in general different from t2->t1!

Actually I'd rather like switches where one gets warnings about unused enum members, but in that case the switch would be 3 times nested and therefore pretty verbose/huge.

If anyone can come up with anything better I'd take it. Till then I'd like at least a warning if I missed to fill an array element.

Comment: -Wmissing-field-initializers ? (see [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html))

Comment: @Caninonos No, these are arrays, not fields in structs.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Indeed, I thought that would work for both, I don't know then.

Comment: Why the downvote? What is wrong with that question? I could not find a switch in the docu and asked a (quite detailed) question on how to achieve what I want

Answer (score 3):

Supplying a smaller number of initializers than the size of the array is a widely used feature. Writing code that looks like this

```
int array[100] = {0};
```

is a common way to default-initialize all array elements. Currently, gcc does not offer a switch to warn about this issue.

One workaround that works only for top-level arrays would be to use `static_assert`, and remove the explicit size, like this:

```
const int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
//             ^^
//     No explicit size

// Check the size here:
static_assert(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) == 4, "Expected four elements");
```

This way you would get a compile-time error if the number of initializers for the array is not equal to the number that you expect (i.e. four).

Comment: I (currently) cannot use C++11 unfortunately. And am I right, that this would not work for the 3D case?

Comment: @Flamefire This would work only for the top level of 3D case. Second and third levels would remain unchecked, though, unless you write individual checks for them (that would double the effort, and would be harder than checking the sizes manually).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a thin `int` wrapper, give it a constructor, and use arrays of that wrapper type. This will not only give you a warning but even an error:

```
struct Integer
{
    Integer(int i) : i(i) {}
    int i;
};

int main()
{
   const Integer array[4] = {1, 2};
}
```

VC error:

```
error C2073: 'array' : elements of partially initialized array must have a default constructor
```

GCC error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Integer::Integer(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

If you use this solution, then you might also consider a conversion operator:

```
struct Integer
{
    Integer(int i) : i(i) {}
    int i;
    operator int() const { return i; }
};

void f(int x) {}

int main()
{
   const Integer array[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   f(array[0]);
}
```